# how do you write a KeyPath to reference the value of a dictionary

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

Say I have a struct like this:

```swift
struct Person {
  var kids: [KidId: KidName] = [:]
}
```

Is it possible to construct a keypath to reference the *value* of something in the `User.kids` property?  Something like `\User.kids[KidId]`?

Specifically, I'd like to construct a `WritableKeyPath<User,KidName>`.  I thought you could keypath into both dictionaries and arrays, but I can't for the life of me find the syntax anywhere on the internet.  Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: What you've written here works exactly as you've described. What trouble are you having? `let kp = \Person.kids[kidId]; user[keyPath: kp]`. Maybe the confusion is that this would be `WritableKeyPath<Person,KidName?>` (i.e. an Optional)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear because you refer to `User` in your text, but have `Person` in your code. That suggests that you might have the syntax right but a hierarchy wrong.

You also may just be forgetting the question mark.

To get the type you're asking about, you also need a `KidID` ([the D is capitalized in Swift](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide/issues/101#issuecomment-393476464)) value, not the `KidID` type.

```swift
typealias KidID = String
enum KidName { case goatBoy }
\Person.kids[""] as WritableKeyPath<Person, KidName?>
Person(kids: ["": .goatBoy])[keyPath: \.kids[""]] // .goatBoy
```

You don't have to supply a value in the key path, but that is a different type.

```swift
\Person.kids as WritableKeyPath<Person, [KidID: KidName]>
Person(kids: ["": .goatBoy])[keyPath: \.kids][""] // .goatBoy
```